# Very simple "just redirect" email server

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I've read that any decent domain must have the email addresses security@domain and abuse@domain. Also, I'll need postmaster@domain if I want to buy a certificate.

I am running just a plain website on a dedicated VM on my domain, so there are no mail boxes there, and I'd rather not to. So, is there any small and simple MTA, with as little as possible configuration files, that listens on port 25, receives the emails for those addresses only, and re-deliver them to my GMail account?

Comment: YES there are try one of the standard Linux MTAs.

Comment: Why was this question closed? How is this question more fit to Super User instead of Server Fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read that any decent domain must have the email addresses security@domain and abuse@domain.

Where? I've not heard that.

Half of the domains I own/run don't have e-mail service at all. Of those that do have e-mail service,  the [RFC 2142 well-known Network Mailboxes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142) work.

> Also, I'll need postmaster@domain if I want to buy a certificate.

This is one of the well-known Support Mailboxes.

If a domain doesn't send e-mail there's no specific suggestion or requirement that it accept e-mail either. The RFC is only a strong suggestion as to what e-mail you should accept (and the Internet reserves the right to arbitrarily block organizations/domains/etc that don't follow these standards.

I get certs for free from StartSSL and they don't require any of the well-known mailboxes.

Answer (score 2):

using postfix is pretty simple

/etc/postfix/main.cf

just set up this line:

relayhost = $mydomain

assuming rest of your configuration such as firewall etc. allows this.

this package is available in all linux versions.

however, delivering to your gmail account is trickier, as gmail may consider it spam if it figures out that an agent is sending it. you need to do more research if that happens. this is what i ran into at one time.

Comment: But isn't relayhost used for emails to alien domains? Also, by doing this, isn't the mail sent back to myself, in an infinite loop?

Comment: oh, you mean your gmail is set up as your domain mail already? in that case, yes, that would create a loop. i was assuming that you only wanted to forward mails to your domain to gmail. gmail provides a service to act as your mail server as well and do not need to set up anything other than on gmail.

Comment: I want to, when someone sends an email to security@mydomain.com, it arrives in my personal Gmail account. Gmail is not setup as my domain mail.

Comment: in that case, if you want to forward to a single email address, you need to set up forwarding in your recipient account in your server instead. just add your gmail address in your ~/.forward will do. you need to point your MX record to your web server. but i still think it is easier to use the gmail app service which is free for a small number of users for your domain. http://deployment.googleapps.com/